# Merge text with button component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Currently, I implemented a custom tab button (using react-native elements) and I added the text of that tab button just below the icon.

```
       <View style={styles.gridBox}>
              {
                timeIdArray.map((_id, index) => (
                  <View style={(this.state.selectedTab === _id) ? styles.tabItemActive : styles.tabItemInActive} key={index}>
                    <TapButton icon={{
                      name: timeSlots[_id - 1],
                      style:styles.icon,
                      type: '_icon', color: (this.state.selectedTab === _id) ? '#01579b' : '#2196F3', size: 30
                    }}
                      buttonStyle={styles._tab}
                      onPress={() => this.changeTab(_id)} />
                    <Text style={(this.state.selectedTab === _id) ? styles.tabberLabelActive : styles.tabberLabelInactive}>{_timeIds[_id - 1]}</Text>
                  </View>
                ))
              }
            </View>

Styles 

gridBox: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'flex-start'
    },
//#region TAB LAYOUT
    tabItem: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginHorizontal : spacing.hairline,
        // marginBottom : spacing.small
    },
tabItemActive: {
        ...BaseStyle.tabItem,
        width: '25%',
        borderTopWidth: spacing.tiny,
        borderTopColor: Colors.activeborder
    },

    tabItemInActive: {
        ...BaseStyle.tabItem,
        width: '25%'
    },
 icon: {
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
tabberLabelActive: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color:'#01579b',
        fontSize: fontSize.fs12,
        lineHeight:spacing.labelLineHeight,
        marginVertical : spacing.small
    },
    tabberLabelInactive: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color:Colors.primary,
        fontSize: fontSize.fs12,
        lineHeight:spacing.labelLineHeight,
        marginVertical : spacing.small
    },

    _Tab: {
        paddingTop: spacing.small,
        height: spacing.buddyiOSTabHeight
    },
```

[image]

In the above code, I only utilize the touch area that acquires the icon size the of tab button. But I want a touchable area Tab button and text as well.

Comment: Can you share a CodeSandbox ?

Comment: @GregMit, code is big. Not able to share in CodeSandbox. But I shared code that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: At least sharing style can be useful in this case

Comment: @GregMit I update my question with styles.